# Keep getting "open in app" warning trying to open "about:blank" on page load

Tags: ios, safari

When I open certain pages on my website [(here is one example)](http://www.sutterhealth.org/dr-venkat-aachi.html) inside my iOS app, I get the "Open in app?" warning but it wants to open "about:blank" (see below). Is there a reason it prompts for that? I'm wondering if scripts that load using the protocol-less style prompt in that way, e.g. `<script src="//service.maxymiser.net..."/>`

[image]

Comment: I think if the site has associated domain with an app it'd ask I guess

Comment: @sathishkumar_kingmaker thanks, I added an image to show what I mean... it isn't referring to another site it's literally asking about "about:blank"